# toString override in C++

Tags: c++, tostring

In Java, when a class overrides `.toString()` and you do `System.out.println()` it will use that.

```
class MyObj {
    public String toString() { return "Hi"; }
}
...
x = new MyObj();
System.out.println(x); // prints Hi
```

How can I accomplish that in C++, so that:

```
Object x = new Object();
std::cout << *x << endl;
```

Will output some meaningful string representation I chose for `Object`?

Comment: You shouldn't dynamically allocate the Object with `new` there (it won't compile).

Comment: in C++, use either `Object* x = new Object(); cout << *x;` or `Object x; cout << x;`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & Str, Object const & v) { 
  // print something from v to str, e.g: Str << v.getX();
  return Str;
}
```

If you write this in a header file, remember to mark the function inline: `inline std::ostream & operator<<(...`  (See the C++ Super-FAQ [for why](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-nonmember-fns).)

Comment: Note that this part is NOT in the class / struct!

Comment: The answer about C++ inline functions in the header by @jalf here on SO seems to more clearly answer why to mark function definitions in the header inline than the FAQ did. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5057179/101151

Comment: I get error: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters

Answer (score 41):

Alternative to Erik's solution you can override the string conversion operator.

```
class MyObj {
public:
    operator std::string() const { return "Hi"; }
}
```

With this approach, you can use your objects wherever a string output is needed. You are not restricted to streams.

However this type of conversion operators may lead to unintentional conversions and hard-to-trace bugs. I recommend using this with only classes that have text semantics, such as a `Path`, a `UserName` and a `SerialCode`.

Comment: However, implicit conversion operators like this one can lead to unpleasant surprises.

Comment: It's better to define both, and have `ostream& operator<<` use the `string` operator. Another thing I would do is renaming the `string` operator to something like `ToString()` member function, reserving string cast for the case when the object is itself kind of a string.

Comment: Avoid implicit conversion operators for non-directly-related types.  They have a tendency to be the source of some very hard to find bugs if used on types that cannot meaningfully be converted to a specific type.

Comment: Points taken and added to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
 class MyClass {
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & _stream, MyClass const & mc) {
        _stream << mc.m_sample_ivar << ' ' << mc.m_sample_fvar << std::endl;
    }

    int m_sample_ivar;
    float m_sample_fvar;
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Though operator overriding is a nice solution, I'm comfortable with something simpler like the following, (which also seems more likely to Java) :

```
char* MyClass::toString() {
    char* s = new char[MAX_STR_LEN];
    sprintf_s(s, MAX_STR_LEN, 
             "Value of var1=%d \nValue of var2=%d\n",
              var1, var2);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This function won't get called when you use `std::cout << myClassInst;`

Comment: As I've stated - it's more likely to Java ... i.e.: It's for usage like:
`printf("myClassInst = %s\n", myClassInst.toString() ) ; `
or like:
`std::cout << myClassInst.toString() ; `

Comment: This is leaking memory