# Syntax errors when trying to overload "<<": too many parameters

Tags: c++, ostream

I've been searching for a while and the closest thing to an answer was over there

[toString override in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171739/tostring-override-in-c)

However I was not able to make it work in my class.

I have a `Table2D.h` which contains this:

```
std::string toString() const;
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & o, const Table2D<T> & s );
```

and I have a template class `Table2D.template` which contains this:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream & :: operator<<( std::ostream & o, const Table2D<T> & s ){
    return out << s.toString();
}
```

when I call my toString() function from main, it functions correctly.
However when I invoke the `<<` operator using a `std::cout` I get the following errors.

```
Table2D.h(59): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters
Table2D.h(85) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Table2D<T>' being compiled
Table2D.template(100): error C2039: '<<' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
Table2D.h(59): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters
```

just so you know the 59'th line contains

```
for (unsigned y=0; y<m_height; y++) col_ptr[y] = (T) col_ptr_src[y];
```

which as you see contains no `<<`'s so I'm not entirely certain what it's referring to.

---

Edit:

After removing the declaration from the class, I replaced it's entry in the header file with this

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Table2D<T>& s ) {
    return o << s.toString();
}
```

and got the following error:

```
Table2D.h(60): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters
Table2D.h(89) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Table2D<T>' being compiled
```

the 89th line in the template file contains `std::stringstream resultStream;`

which is the very first line in my toString function, which looks like this

```
template <class T>
std::string Table2D<T> :: toString() const{
    std::stringstream resultStream;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i< m_height; i++){
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m_width; j++){
            resultStream << (*this)[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        resultStream << endl;
    }
    return resultStream.str();
}
```

Comment: thank's @pst I'm having a lot of trouble identifying errors with c++ so my question names can be a little off. Thank's again.

Comment: In case you don't know, click on the number circled in red on the top left of the page to see the comments directed at you via the @-symbol. If you do you'll see my comment to you in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from your syntax being wrong<sup>1</sup>, `operator<<` overloads on other classes (`ostream` in this case) must be non-member functions. Change your definition to

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, const Table2D<T>& s ) {
    return o << s.toString();
}
```

and remove its declaration from the class completely so that it is a free function.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case you want to know why, member-function binary operators only take one argument, because the left side is the invoking object, accessed via `this`. Also, you forgot the `Table2D<T>` before the `::` in the definition. But even if you fixed these it wouldn't work as intended because, as previously stated, operator overloading on other classes must be done through free functions.

Comment: I don't know how to post code in these comment boxes so I'll just edit my post with the reply gimme a sec

Comment: @vvMINOvv update your code in your question to reflect exactly what you're compiling now, and update the error you're getting (copy and paste it, don't try to type it).

Comment: I swear I love this place. You guys are awesome.

Comment: @vvMINOvv just to make sure, you have `template <typename T>` above the `operator<<` thing, and also it is **completely outside the class**, right? Not inside the class's curly braces? And yeah, SO is a cool place.

Comment: @Seth_Carnegie thank's buddy, you've been really patient with me.

Comment: @Seth_Carnegie so yea I just checked and it's exactly as you told me to write it. I have 

`template <class T>` right above in the header file, under `public:`

Comment: @vvMINOvv yeah, it shouldn't be under public, it should be outside the class completely. Example: http://pastebin.com/suy0tQ0Z

Comment: @Seth_Carnegie wow.....that is bizzarre, how does it know which scope `toString()` I was referring to then?  is it because of the s parameter?

Comment: @vvMINOvv because of the type of `s`, yes. The compiler knows everything about it (because of its type which it has already seen) including all its member functions, so it knows what to do.