# Can I implement .ToString() on C++ structs for debugging purposes?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

In C#, if I define a struct, I can also override ToString(). Then when I'm debugging and I add a watch or hover my mouse over an instance of the struct, the tooltip will be the computed ToString() rather than the type name of the struct.

Can I do that in C++ and/or C++/CLI somehow? That is, can I define a method as part of the struct (or do anything else) that will cause the watch-value/tooltip to display a string of my choosing? The default string rendering in Visual Studio for C/C++ is a list of all the struct's field values (or as many as can be jammed into the little box).

My types all C-style structs. (It was actually written in C before I converted the files to .cpp and fixed some type issues so I could run it in CLI.) Here's an example struct:

```
struct other_dollars_node
{
    struct other_dollars_node *next_other_dollars;
    override *overrides;    
    long     other_dollars_id;
    tm       effective_date;
    double   amount;
}
```

I have very little experience with C++/CLI -- most of my experience has been with native C/C++ and C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

**Update: since almost all the existing code uses native C syntax, and I would prefer a solution that works without having to refactor it, the CLI aspect may be less important.**

Comment: check this out to see if it sheds any light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171739/tostring-override-in-c

Comment: Please clarify, are your structs plain unmanaged structs (`struct foo`) or managed structs (`public value struct foo` or `public value class foo`)? Maybe show us one of the simpler structs?

Comment: Have you tried a NatVis? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx I know its not quite what you asked for but it may be what you need

Comment: @157: The second answer to question 5171739 looks pretty close to what I want, except it doesn't affect what's displayed in the tooltip, and I can't call std::string(variableName) in the Watch window because it says "identifier "std::string" is undefined. So it's only useful for actually calling from the code which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Mike Vine: I will check out NatVis. A cursory reading of the description suggests it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ Mike Vine -- NatVis is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't (currently) work with mixed mode code, but I can compile and debug in native since that's what the code actually is. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using VS 2013, "managed C++" is no longer a thing (only in VS 2005). C++/CLI is the correct term.

Comment: @crashmstr: Actually, Managed Extensions for C++ were in VS 2002 and VS.NET 2003.  VS 2005 is when C++/CLI replaced them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to provide a debugger visualization for your native structs. I did a little searching on MSDN, and found this page: [Create custom views of native objects in the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx).

Basically, what you need to do is add a file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` to tell Visual Studio how to show your structs in the debugger window. There are many examples there, and the link above provides some good explanation, though I admit I haven't tried it myself.