# C++ toString operator similair to Object.toString

Tags: java, c++, tostring

In Java every Object has a toString method and a hashcode method.
Is there an equivalent hashcode and toString for each object in C++?

Comment: Nope.  If you want that you have to write it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I implement .ToString() on C++ structs for debugging purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597189/can-i-implement-tostring-on-c-structs-for-debugging-purposes)

Comment: There is [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for built-in types, but that's it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl one can specialise it for custom types too

Comment: @UKMonkey Sure, but I got the impression that OP was asking about what was available off the bat.

Comment: No everithing has sense. Most similar techniques in Java/C# have sense only with reflection

Comment: The most universal way to stringize objects in C++ is to [provide an overload of `operator <<` for `std::ostream`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476272/7571258) and on some platforms like Windows also `std::wostream`. Doesn't work automatically for all types, but the nice thing about this mechanism is that you can write your own overload if the original author of the type doesn't provide one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent. Unlike JAVA, not everything in C++ is derived from some (`Object`) superclass. There is no `::toString()` member function as there is no superclass in C++ to begin with. C++ does not support reflection either.

That being said, there is a [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function having 9 different overloads for the built-in types. To achieve the functionality you want, you can [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) the output stream [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for each of your classes.

Comment: `operator <<` for `std::ostream` deserves being mentioned too.

Comment: Darn. Well I guess I will just have to infiltrate apple headquarters and hit the CEO with a pipe until he agrees to give good java support :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like this built-in the language. Not everything in C++ is an object(there's no common class from which everything derives).

Comment: Besides functions, and maybe templates everything in C++ is an object.

Comment: Comparing to Java, where everything(?) is a subclass of Object - there's no such thing in cpp. Of course ints, chars and everything else are PODs but there's no common interface for all of them. This is what I meant.

Comment: There is a distinction between a class type and an object. There are many non-class type objects. It would be more accurate to say "Not everything in c++ is a class type."

Comment: @tomdol Maybe rephrase it then that in C++, not everything is derived from a `Object` class?