# C++: Output for Polynomial Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, cout

I have a polynomial of the type `std::vector<T>` and a matrix of the type `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, with classes for both of them. The output (in my case void print()-function) for each of those classes works fine. Now I created a matrix consisting of multiple polynomials, [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_matrix), and I'm not entirely sure how to create an output for it.

Suppose I have a polynomial p1: `Polynomial<T> p1{0,1,2}`. My Polynomial::print function interprets it correctly and returns: `x^2+x+1`.
For a 'normal' matrix of the type `Matrix<T> m1(2,2,0)`, a 2x2-matrix filled with 0's, it is correctly returned with Matrix::print() as well as:

```
0, 0
0, 0
```

Now, suppose I want a polynomial matrix m1: `Matrix<Polynomial<T>> mp(2,2,p1)`, a 2x2-matrix filled polynomial p1 from before. The code is accepted, but now I want to print the matrix using matrix::print(), so that I get:

```
x^2+x+1, x^2+x+1
x^2+x+1, x^2+x+1
```

Minimal working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Polynomial;

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
  Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T> > ma);
  Matrix(int rows, int cols, T const & init);
  Matrix(const Matrix & m);
  ~Matrix();
  Matrix ();
  void print();
  friend void Polynomial<T>::print();

private:
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> Ma;
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> ma)
  :Ma(ma)
  {}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int rows, int cols, T const & init)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<T>> b(rows, std::vector<T>(cols, init));
  Ma=b;
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
  {}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() :
Matrix(1,1,0)
{}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix & m)
{
  Ma = m.Ma;
}


template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::print()
{
  for (auto i = 0; i < Ma.size(); i++)
  {
    for (auto j = 0; j < Ma[i].size(); j++)
      if ( j == Ma.size()-1 )
      {
    cout << Ma[i][j]; //This causes problems
      }
      else
    cout << Ma[i][j] << ", \t";
    cout << endl;
  }
}

template <typename T>
class Polynomial
{
    public:
    Polynomial(std::vector<T> const& coef);
    Polynomial(std::initializer_list<T> const& coef);
    void print();
    const int getdeg();
    const T getKoeff(int index) const;

    friend class Matrix<T>;
    Polynomial ();

    friend void print();

    private:
    std::vector<T> coefficient;

};

template <typename T>
Polynomial<T>::Polynomial(std::vector<T> const& coef) :
    coefficient(coef)
{}

template <typename T>
Polynomial<T>::Polynomial(std::initializer_list<T> const& coef) :
    coefficient(coef)
{}

template <typename T>
Polynomial<T>::Polynomial ()
{
  coefficient = new std::vector<T> [coefficient.getdeg()];
  coefficient[0]=0;
}

template <typename T>
void Polynomial<T>::print() //Reduced version for demonstration purposes, but
{
    for ( int i = getdeg(); i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        cout << coefficient[i] << "x^" << i; //the output is always  of the type cout << xyz
    }
}

template <typename T>
const int Polynomial<T>::getdeg()
{
  int g = coefficient.size()-1;
    return g;
}

int main()
{

 typedef double T;    
  Polynomial<T> p1{0,1,2};
  p1.print();

  Matrix<Polynomial<T>> mp(2, 3, Polynomial<T>{0});
//  mp.print(); //When this is commented out chaos ensues
  return 0;
}
```

`2x^21x^10` is returned (Note: +&- excluded from the notation, since the code would be too long).

The matrix::print() might cause problems due to `cout` having problems handling the result of the polynomial.
Anybody have an idea how to make matrix::print() give useful results for a polynomial matrix? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print content of `Map[i][j]` (it is `Polynomial<double>`) by using `operator<<` but operator which takes as argument `Polynomial<double>` is not defined. So you should add declaration

```
template<class U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Polynomial<U>&);
```

in your `Polynomial` template and make definition outside class as

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Polynomial<T>& poly)
{
  poly.print();
  return out;
}
```

then you can call

```
cout << Ma[i][j] << ", ";
```

in your `Matrix<T>::print` method.

Comment: Thanks mate. But there still seems to be a problem, when calling Matrix<T>::print(): "In instantiation of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Polynom<T>&) [with T = double; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]': required from 'void Matrix<T>::print() [with T = Polynom<double>]'

Comment: @Retze Ohh my mistake, in `operator<<()` Polynomial<T> is declared with `const` qualifier, so there are two solutions: you add `const` to `print` method in Polynomial class (for const object you can call only const methods) or you remove const from operator<< -> `operator<<(std::ostream& out, Polynomial<T>& poly)`. Remember that from `print` method you are calling `getdeg` so if `print` will be const, `getdeg` should be too as const.

Answer (score 1):

In `Matrix<T>::print()` you are trying to call

```
cout << Ma[i][j];
```

and when `Ma[i][j]` is a `Polynomial<double>`, there is no matching overload for the output operator. You could call `Ma[i][j].print()` instead, but then your `Matrix` wont work for `int`. [Long story short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269423/c-what-is-wrong-with-using-a-tostring-method): Instead of writing your own `print()` you better overload `operator<<(std::ostream&,const T&)` for your types.

For `Polynomial` that would be something along the line of (I allowed myself to strip your code down quite a bit and to add the "+"):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template <typename T> struct Polynomial { std::vector<T> data; };

template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const Polynomial<T>& pol) {        
    auto power = [](int n){ 
        return (n==0) ? "" : (n==1) ? "x" : "x^" + std::to_string(n);
    };
    auto sign = [&](int i){ 
        return (pol.data[i]<0 || i==pol.data.size()-1) ? "" : "+";
    }; 
    // DO THIS ONLY AT HOME !!!  --------v        
    for (size_t i = pol.data.size()-1; i < pol.data.size(); i-- ) {
        o << sign(i) << pol.data[i] << power(i); 
    }
    return o;
}

int main() {
    Polynomial<double> p1{{0,1,2,-3,4}};
    std::cout << p1 << "\n";
}
```

Prints

> 4x^4-3x^3+2x^2+1x+0

You dont need to write desctructors/constructors that the compiler can write for you. Actually it doesnt need any constructor as long at is just a bare `std::vector` in disguise. Note that I tried to keep it short, but not necessarily clean, for example I would never rely on [unsigned overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056758/c-c-unsigned-integer-overflow) for a loop condition in any serious code, and heavy use of the [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator) doesnt really boost readability. However, I am serious about using [lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11). They help to keep stuff localized. I'll leave it to you to print nothing for the last coefficient in case it is `0` ;).

To print rows of the matrix you could provide an overload for `std::vector<T>`, that would be something along the line of:

```
template <typename T> struct Matrix {
      using element_type = T;
      using row_type = std::vector<element_type> ;
      using data_type = std::vector<row_type> ;
      Matrix(int rows, int cols, T const & init) : 
          data(data_type(rows,row_type(cols,init)))
      {}
      data_type data;
};

template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const std::vector<T>& v) {
    for (auto& x : v) o << x << "\t";
    return o;
}

template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o,const Matrix<T>& mat) {
    for (const auto& row : mat.data) o << row << "\n";
    return o;
}
```

Now printing a matrix is as simple as this

```
int main() { 
    using Matrix = Matrix<Polynomial<double>>;
    Polynomial<double> p1{{1,2}};
    Matrix mp(2,3,p1);
    std::cout << mp;
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

> 2x+1  2x+1    2x+1
>   2x+1  2x+1    2x+1

See also here: https://ideone.com/n00bqn 
(is ideone trying to make fun of me or what? :)

Comment: Wow dude, this is what I call an elegant approach and it works just as fine. Thanks a for your input.

Comment: @Retze please take it with a grain of salt (or rather a bag of salt ;). For example only after writing the answer I realized that it would have been nicer to print the rows inside `operator<<(ostream,Matrix)` instead of supplying `operator<<` for `vector<T>`. I hope you wont simply copy/paste it, but adapt it to your needs. If anything is unclear, please ask