# Making my own toString() method on c++ struct

Tags: c++

I'm used to oveerriding the Java toString() method on my own objects in classes, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the following code:

```
    struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double finalGrade;

    std::string toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\n Age: " + age + "\n Final Grade: " + finalGrade;
    }
};
```

I'm only beginning to learn c++ so any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot add an `int` to an `std::string`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269423/c-what-is-wrong-with-using-a-tostring-method

Comment: @user463035818 just still trying to familiarise myself with what works and how to best do things

Comment: String interpolation and concatenation doesn't work the same in C++ as in Java. To achieve what you're attempting here, you should look up `stringstream`s.

Comment: @whelanevan6 sure, there was nothing between the lines in my comment, but I suggest you to be aware that java and c++ are two very different languages.

Comment: Be aware that nothing in C++ expects a `toString` method on an object, so it won't get used automatically. You'll have to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 17):

In contrast to java, C++ does not offer a predefined "toString"-method that is called implicitly whenever a string representation of an object is requested. So your `toString`-method will have to be called explicitly then.

In C++, however, something similar is available by overriding the `operator <<` for streams. Thereby, you can directly "send" the object contents to a stream (without the need to store everything in an intermediate string object). And you can use the same code to populate a string to be returned by a `toString`method,   too:

```
struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double finalGrade;

    std::string toString() const;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Student &s) {
    return (os << "Name: " << s.name << "\n Age: " << s.age << "\n Final Grade: " << s.finalGrade  << std::endl);
}

std::string Student::toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << (*this);
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {

    Student stud { "john baker", 25, 1.2 };
    std::cout << "stud directly: " << stud << endl;
    std::string studStr = stud.toString();
    std::cout << "stud toString:" << studStr << endl;
}
```

Comment: This. C++ doesn't use `toString`, C++ uses `operator<<`.

Answer (score 10):

You can't add anything you want to a `std::string` like you can to a Java `String`. Notably, most objects are not expected to have a `toString` member function. However, the standard library provides [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) which allow you to convert numeric values to an `std::string`. For example you could wrap the numeric values with a `std::to_string` to fix your function :

```
#include <string>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    double finalGrade;

    std::string toString() {
        return "Name: " + 
            name + 
            "\n Age: " + 
            std::to_string(age) + 
            "\n Final Grade: " + 
            std::to_string(finalGrade);
    }
};
```

Edit : Though this answer explains why what you tried doesn't work, the other answer's solution is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 6):

You cant add int to std::string because the `std::string` `operator+` was not overloaded to int.

The best solution is to use string stream :

```
#include <sstream>

std::string toString() {
    std::ostringstream strout;
    strout<< "Name: " << name << "\n Age: " << age << "\n Final Grade: " << finalGrade;
    return strout.str();
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::string`, just use proper overloads.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just add an `int` or a `double` to an `std::string`. Use [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to convert them first. This should work fine:

```
std::string toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "\n Age: " + std::to_string(age) + "\n Final Grade: " + std::to_string(finalGrade);
}
```

Or, in C++20 you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).