# C++ inline methods realization

Tags: c++, inline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C++ inline functions in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057021/why-are-c-inline-functions-in-the-header)

Is it any difference between write inline method realization in header or cpp-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline` makes sense in the header, along with the function definition. If it's in an implementation file, multiple definition isn't an issue, and the compiler will have a hard time inlining it anyway outside that translation unit (and inside that translation unit, it probably won't matter anyway - it's just a hint).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, functionally, the answer is no. Semantically, inline doesn't make any sense in the cpp file.