# Why can I not inline a function in my class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline

I am learning c++ by writing commons data structures and I have a compiler warning that my inlined add method is not defined.

```
src/vector.h:10:14: warning: inline function 'Vector::add' is not defined
      [-Wundefined-inline]
        inline void add(const float val);
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell the methods match up. However if I remove the inline method, it works fine but the first invocation of add takes 11380us but the 2nd and 3rd are around 3667us -nearly 4x penalty cost.

src/vector.h

```
//#include <cstddef>

class Vector {
public:
    explicit Vector(const int n);
    explicit Vector(const int n, const float val);
    float& operator[](const int i);
    inline int const length();
    inline void fill(const float val);
    inline void add(const float val);
    inline float sum();
private:
    float* arr;
    int len;
};
```

src.vector.cpp

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "yepCore.h"
#include "yepMath.h"
#include "yepLibrary.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

inline void Vector::add(const float val)
{
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        arr[i] += val;
    }
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "yepp add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";
}

/**
template <>
void Vector<float>::add(const float val)
{
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();   
    yepCore_Add_V32fS32f_V32f(arr, val, arr, len);
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "yepp add took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "us.\n";

}
...
```

Comment: I should point out that it was templated but removed it to simplify and debug as I thought it was because of the templating but the problem still exists.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057021/why-are-c-inline-functions-in-the-header

Comment: This is not duplicated because I have added a definition in the header. Please read my question before marking duplicated.

Comment: that's a declaration, not a definition.  I did not dup this, but it's pretty well-trodden ground.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline functions must be defined in the header. If they are not defined in the header file, then the function cannot be inlined, because callers won't have the definition.

Comment: They can be defined in a source file if they are only used in the source file. And functions not in a header can still be inlined.

Comment: @NeilKirk Then you will have a different declaration and definition of the class.

Comment: @NeilKirk Because you are defining a function that was not declared. It would still compile and work, but just semantically they are different.

Comment: @Zan but I have added an inlined add method in my header file though?