# Function having release version inline on h file and debug version implemented on cpp

Tags: c++, mfc, conditional-compilation, release-builds, debug-build

I am maintaing a legacy MFC application and I see a pattern exactly like the one on [Object-Oriented Programming under Windows](https://books.google.pt/books?id=nj6eBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22non-debug%20version%20is%20inline%22&source=bl&ots=Ea8kop_963&sig=axH5I769PifEWtPQCw4IQiOWuEk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy87rd3qrbAhXMaxQKHfnfBUkQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22non-debug%20version%20is%20inline%22&f=false) book, where the relevant part is:

**Persview.h**

```
#ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in persview.cpp
inline CPersDoc* CPersView::GetDocument()
   { return (CPersDoc*)m_pDocument; }
#endif
```

**Persview.cpp**

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
CPersDoc* CPersView::GetDocument() // non-debug version is inline
{
    ASSERT(m_pDocument->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CPersView)));
    return (CPersView*)m_pDocument;
}
#endif //_DEBUG
```

I see the pattern widely applied if I search for it on Internet, so I presume it is wizard generated code.

My question is: Is there any advantage or another good reason for the release version being inlined on the .h file and the debug on the .cpp file? Why not put both on the same file next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

Take note, that the book you are quoting was published in 1994. C++ was very different back then, and Microsoft's C++ compiler wasn't. At a guess, `inline` had different semantics back then, and instructed the compiler to inline the function call, even in debug configurations.

With that out of the way, there are technical reasons: A compiler can only inline a function, if it sees the full definition. If you want it inlined in a different compilation unit, the function definition needs to be in the header file. On the other hand, you cannot place the non-inline function in a header, because that would violate the One Definition Rule, if the header gets included into more than one compilation unit. You'd get linker errors in that case.

If you wish to get rid of the code duplication and still get the same benefits, you can: Simply move the **debug** version into the header, mark it `inline`, and remove the preprocessor conditionals. The `ASSERT`compiles to nothing in a non-debug configuration, and the compiler can (probably will) inline the function call. For a debug configuration, the compiler will not perform any optimizations, and emits code for a function call. Function calls are desirable in debug configurations, as they produce more meaningful stacktraces.

Answer (score 1):

For the non-debug build the advantage is that the header file is precisely where an `inline` function definition [belongs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057065/1332041), so that multiple `#include`'s only see one definition of it.

For the debug build where the function is not inlined, the advantage is that you keep with the convention of declarations and definitions being separate - the definition is where you'd expect to find it.

i.e. You wouldn't put them together in the header file because that is unexpected when not `inline`, and you wouldn't put them together in the source file because that would be wrong when it is `inline`.