# can compiler deciding not to inline a function lead to multiple definitions?

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

I know that the compiler can decide whether to inline a function or not. Lets say someone defined a function as `inline` in a header file and the function body is also in the header file. Also, say the function is long and the compiler decides NOT to actually inline this function.

f1.h:

```
inline void f1()
{
    /* really long function */
}
```

What now happens to the function when it is included in multiple cpp translation units -- would that not break the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) and cause multiple definitions at linking time? Or does that `inline` property remain, even if it's not actually inlined?

foo.cpp:

```
#include "f1.h"
/* code here */
```

bar.cpp:

```
#include "f1.h"
/* code here */
```

Comment: Did you research what `inline` means? See [cppreference inline specified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) the `2.` point in Explanation.

Comment: It doesn't matter if compiler inlines function or not. Keyword `inline` is your promise to the compiler, which says "There may be multiple definitions of this function, but I guarantee they will all be identical, allow it under ODR".

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why are C++ inline functions in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057021/why-are-c-inline-functions-in-the-header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Any "optimization decisions" made by the compiler during compilation will never lead to a compile error. So the answer is NO.