# Undefined reference to inlining function with const reference parameters from test case

Tags: c++, inline

In a function that doesn't keep the parameters immutable, with potentially large size, therefore pass by reference, defined to be inline, i get the error undefined reference at compile time, removing the inlining makes it compile.
here is my declaration:

```
  inline Eigen::VectorXd
  ForwardDynamics(const Eigen::VectorXd &, const Eigen::VectorXd&);
```

definition:

```
inline Eigen::VectorXd
Kinetics::ForwardDynamics(const Eigen::VectorXd &taulist,
                          const Eigen::VectorXd &Ftip) {
  Eigen::VectorXd tau = taulist;
  Eigen::VectorXd Ft = Ftip;
  

  //... code is a bit long ...
  // but taulist, Ftip never used.
  // .........

  return res;
}
```

called from the test case, i get the following error at compile time:

> undefined reference to
> `Kinetics::ForwardDynamics(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>
> const&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&)'

an analogous example like

```
#include <iostream>

struct Info {
  int i;
};

typedef Info info;

class A {
public:
  A() {
  }

  inline void display_info(const info &f) {
    std::cout << f.i << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **args) {
  A a;
  info f{2408};
  a.display_info(f);
}
```

would compile fine, so the problem clearly from the test environment i'm using which is gtest, or the Eigen library itself, considering Eigen, and gtest as black box, what do you expect the reason of this problem?

Comment: yes sure, implemented, and i said it compiles without the inlining!

Comment: I'm guessing, but is the function definition put in a different file than he function declaration?

Comment: yes, in header, and src

Comment: Move the definition into the header. That should be all there is to it.

Comment: and, viola! can you explain why?

Comment: In order to inline the function every time its used, it must have its definition available. I'll see if I can find a better answer here on SO..Edit: Does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057021/why-are-c-inline-functions-in-the-header) make it clear?

Comment: Just read on what inline is and does.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sure, it does.