# Is it bad practice to define small functions inside the header file?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering, is it bad practice to define small functions, such as getters and setters, that only influence the member variables of the function and don't depend on external header file includes?

I am specifying that they don't depend on external header files so as to make it clear that I am trying to avoid circular includes.

Here is one example from a recent program I am writing:

```
void EnableDirtyFlag() { m_DirtyFlag = true; }
```

Comment: You have to remember to define them as either `static` or `inline`, or possibly both. That way you won't get multiple-definition errors.

Comment: I would say it's good practise, it's good to have the same code acting as declaration and definition if possible. Do you think different? What's your concern?

Comment: The downside is that if you change the definition of the function you have to recompile every source file that uses that header. If the definition is in its own source file you only have to recompile that source file.

Comment: @john -- ignoring the difference between declarations and definitions can lead to massive recompilations. That's why they are different things, and deciding to do both in the same place is not automatically good.

Comment: Defining a function in a header file - whether small or not - is not on its own a "bad practice".

Comment: For small or medium sized projects, it's fine.  For larger projects, it incurs an incremental build churn penalty that can become prohibitive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't know you could stop multiple-definition errors like that, good to know!

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh okay, thank you for the info! I wasn't aware of the recompilation. So in very large projects, this could take a lot of time which would lower the efficiency correct?

Comment: @Alex - You also have to consider what are the odds that you ever have to change this function (without changing the class itself). It's not like you will change `= true` to `= false`, right?

Comment: for templates thats your only option, so it must be basically OK

Comment: As it probably is a member function, static or inline are not necessary, if it is defined inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to [why you’re allowed to define them there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057021/8586227).  Doing so makes it easier for the compiler to inline things and comes with the bonus of avoiding duplicating the signature between a declaration and a definition, but has the disadvantages of introducing additional coupling between source files and increasing compilation time.  Which of these is more important in any given case is a question of professional judgment.