# Why can extern be applied to definitions?

Tags: c++, c, extern

Why is this legal?

```
extern int foo = 0xF00; // Gets a warning, still compiles

extern void bar() { // No warning
  int x;
}
```

Is there a reason to why this is allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful

```
extern const int foo = 0xF00;
```

Without the `extern`, in C++ `foo` would be `static` and have internal linkage (which means you could not use `foo` from another translation unit).

The `extern` in both cases in your example is redundant. [In C99 an `extern` can make a difference for `inline` functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217628/multiple-definition-of-inline-functions-when-linking-static-libs/2218034#2218034).

Comment: @ninjalj yes, that's right. In C `foo` would have external linkage even without `extern`.

Answer (score 2):

In the function case, I think it is just like writing:

```
extern void bar();
void bar()
{
  int x;
}
```

which must be legal since a file with the definition may include a header with such a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, in the C standard, a definition is treated just like a declaration with an initializer, so everything that applies to declarations applies equally to definitions.

(Actually, a definition would be a declaration that allocates storage for a variable, so C's tentative definitions (which don't have initializers) would qualify, and those C++'s declarations that act as definitions without having initializers would also qualify. The point that a definition is essentially a declaration plus some added behaviour still applies).